# Thermal Power Dissipation vs Electrical Power Consumption of a CPU

Tags: thermodynamics

TLDR: If we made a CPU with ideal components, will it consume energy?

I'm aware that TDP is a rough measurement for the full load thermal power dissipation of a CPU. And assume  But in theory, can it be Dissipated Thermal Energy= 100% of power consumption? If it is, does organizing data do not consume any form of energy?

Any (data) storage mediums do not store energy. But it rearranges bits. This should change their entropy. This suggests energy consumption.

My question is does it cost energy to rearrange bits? Then what is the energy conversion as energy cannot be destroyed? If no energy is consumed, is there no entropy change?

PS: I know there can be both active and reactive power consumptions so thermal output(watts) may not equal Volt x Amp.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you make CPU with *ideal components*, it will still use electricity for operation and therefore will generate heat. CPUs operate on DC, so forget about active and reactive power. The DC power is defined simply as voltage times current. I have never heard of transistors (basic building blocks) that work at zero voltage or zero current, not even as a theoretical concept.

By the *Law of conservation of energy*, the total energy of an isolated system remains the same. Therefore, the electrical power from voltage times current is (almost) 100% converted to heat power. In case of LEDs, some energy is converted to light, but still most of it to heat.

You may say there is an ideal transistor (switch), but there will always be some finite resistance, capacitance and inductance that will generate losses. It is just how transistors work - they need voltage and they need charge to move.

Comment: That made me more confused. Why does an ideal transistor (switch) dissipate heat? V_ON = V_SAT = 0

Comment: @Salitha You may say there is an ideal transistor (switch), but there will always be some finite resistance, capacitance and inductance that will generate losses. It is just how transistors work - they need voltage and they need charge to move.

Comment: @salitha there is always a capacitance to charge up or discharge from a source or to ground and whose voltage is *different* from that of the source of the ground, and thus a dissipating current is to be sunk.

Comment: From an information theory standpoint, manipulating bits of information will change the entropy of a system and since that entropy change occurs at some finite temperature it therefore requires the expenditure of work- even if all the components in the system are lossless.

However, the amount of work needed to flip a bit in the information sense is vastly smaller than that which is required to flip the conduction state of a real-world transistor which contains resistance, capacitance and inductance.